# Making a formula in excel

Tags: excel

So I never worked with excel, but I would like to know if it is possible to do the following:
I want to put in a cell , an equation (e,g 2x^3-x), and I would want to make another cell use that formula, but replacing the 'x' with the value from said cell. In other words, creating a template of an equation, to be used in diferrent cells!

How can I do this ? Is it even possible?
Sorry if I'm asking something stupid!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the `x` in your formula with a range reference: `2*A1^3-A1`

You can create a named range and name it `x` then use `2*x^3-x`

[image]

Comment: You can even put the power (3) in a cell as well, so Scott’s second version (in cell B4) becomes : =2*x^A1-x , which means you can easily change the variable x and the power 3 which is in cell A1.